# Is it possible to build buildroot system using Docker for Windows (mapping a Windows folder)?

Tags: docker, buildroot

Using this docker image:

```
docker build -t batocera-docker https://github.com/batocera-linux/batocera.docker.git
```

I launch a container this way, so that the sources are available in F:\docker Windows folder for browsing.

```
docker run -it -v F:\docker:/build batocera-docker
```

The following commands start the build process:

```
git clone git://git.buildroot.net/buildroot
cd buildroot/
make pc_x86_64_bios_defconfig
make
```

Which fails when processing the "host-gmp" component:

```
>>> host-gmp 6.1.2 Building
```

The build fails with the following error (but from experiment, it seems it does not always fail on the same files).

```
m4: cannot open `invert_limb_table.asm': No such file or directory
```

This is a "strange" because, the following command shows the file exists where it should (and issuing the "cat" command shows a valid file content!).

```
root@fe9bc1b08539:/build/buildroot# ls -la 
/build/buildroot/output/build/host-gmp-6.1.2/mpn/invert_limb_table.asm lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Feb 12 22:01 /build/buildroot/output/build/host-gmp-6.1.2/mpn/invert_limb_table.asm -> ../mpn/x86_64/invert_limb_table.asm
```

Sometimes, the error states "File handle stale".

However, such errors always occur on symbolic links files (symlinks or hardlinks?)

I'm confused because creating a symbolic link in the mounted folder seems to work (it works using the ln command), but then it fails at some point, as if the overlay file system of the container was not synchronizing its content with the mounted folder "fast enough"?

Would there be any work around?
(I could build in a container folder, but that is trivial and not much useful to me as the sources are not available from outside).

Comment: Is virtualisation with shared folder not acceptable option for you?

Comment: You mean using VirtualBox and shared folders? It could. In fact, I tried it and ran into many issues as well (maybe/probably similar issues, I don't remember in details)...

Also, I tried to "resolve/remove" symlinks before resuming the build, but then some files (6 in the case of host-gmp where it first stops) would remain in a strange state.